# New SHA1-key for Google Maps V2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play, sha1

I used debug SHA1-key for testing in-App purchases in Google Play. But with debug key not working Google Maps V2, I only see a gray screen instead of cards. I generated the release key, build new apk file and now i can`t upload this file to Google Play.

```
Upload failed You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):
SHA1: XX:XX:XX..XX
and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):
SHA1: YY::YY:YY…YY
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

As you have generated the key with the debug SHA-1 it will not allow any application to uploaded on market which has debug key. Try to generate your key with release certificate fingerprint.

AFAIK for the previous apk generation you have used the release certificate fingerprint and right now for the current you are using the debug SHA-1 that is why the error throwing.

*To display the SHA-1 fingerprint for your certificate, first ensure that you are using the right certificate. You may have two certificates:*

**Debug certificate:** The Android SDK tools generate this certificate automatically when you do a "debug" build from the command line, or when you build and run a project from Eclipse without exporting it as a released application. Only use this certificate with apps that you're testing; do not attempt to publish an app that's signed with a debug certificate. The debug certificate is described in more detail in the section Signing in Debug Mode in the Android Developer Documentation.

**Release certificate:** The Android SDK tools generate this certificate when you do a "release" build with either ant program or Eclipse. You can also generate this certificate using the keytool program. Use this certificate when you are ready to release your app to the world.

[Read More..](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

Answer (score -1):

Me too faced the same problem during releasing my app to google Play, when I used Google Maps V2 in my app. After succeeding the issue, I wrote a blog post regarding this you can have a [look](http://smdaudhilbe.wordpress.com/2014/02/19/how-to-create-release-keystore-digitally-sign-publish-android-app-to-google-play-android-market/).

As everyone requested, I would say the answer in following steps
1) Sign up your app using eclipse adt
2) Note down the SHA1 finger print which will be displayed at console of your eclipse adt
3) Again go to google console and get API_KEY for your app by using above got SHA1 fingerprint
4) Replace the old API_KEY with the new API_KEY on to manifest.xml of your app
5) Again sign up your app. Your app is ready to be published. But keep in mind that once you published your app to google market, you should be able to release updates to your app by signing **.apk** using the keystore which you used earlier for release.

Hope this helps ...

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.